# Gradle - copy jar to another folder as part of the 'jar' task

Tags: gradle

I have a multi project gradle setup. I want to simply copy the generated jar file of any project anytime the jar is rebuild and thought this would work in my root project's subprojects closure:

```
task copyJarToGenerated(type: Copy) {
    from jar
    into "../my-generated-jars/"
}
copyJarToGenerated.mustRunAfter jar
```

But if I run the 'clean' task then 'jar' task of any sub project, my jar is generated under build/libs as usual but not copied.

Looking at the gradle output, it only runs compileJava, processResources, classes then jar. It isn't running copyJarToGenerated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `mustRunAfter` does not define a task dependency, it just enforces a specific order. It basically says 'if both tasks are executed in a build (for whatever reason), then they are executed in the specified order'.

So you need to define the task dependency on your own:

```
jar.finalizedBy copyJarToGenerated
```

You could also just add `copyJarToGenerated` as a dependency of the lifecycle task `build`:

```
build.dependsOn copyJarToGenerated
```

Since you specify the task `jar` in the method `from` of your task, it is registered as a task input and therefor registered as a task dependency implicitly. So you won't need to define order with `mustRunAfter` anymore.

You may also consider using the property `destinationDirectory` of the task `jar` instead of creating a new task at all.